# ESP8266-07 no work after reboot

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide

I try move my projects from atmega to ESP8266-07 modules. I connect ESP8266-07 to FT232:

```
(ESP) RX -------- TX (FT232)
(ESP) TX -------- RX (FT232)
(ESP) GND ------- GND (FT232)
(ESP) VCC ------- VCC 3.3V (FT232)
(ESP) EN -------- VCC 3.3V (FT232)
(ESP) GPIO0 ----- GND (FT232)
(ESP) GPIO15 ---- GND (FT232)
```

I can upload sketch and it's work. BUT...

... WHEN I restart ESP (software reset or hardware reset - unplug power) program no starting. I try change connections after upload like:

```
Try 1:
(ESP) RX -------- TX (FT232)
(ESP) TX -------- RX (FT232)
(ESP) GND ------- GND (FT232)
(ESP) VCC ------- VCC 3.3V (FT232)
(ESP) EN -------- VCC 3.3V (FT232)

Try 2:
(ESP) RX -------- TX (FT232)
(ESP) TX -------- RX (FT232)
(ESP) GND ------- GND (FT232)
(ESP) VCC ------- VCC 3.3V (FT232)
(ESP) EN -------- VCC 3.3V (FT232)
(ESP) GPIO0 ----- VCC 3.3V (FT232)

Try 3:
(ESP) RX -------- TX (FT232)
(ESP) TX -------- RX (FT232)
(ESP) GND ------- GND (FT232)
(ESP) VCC ------- VCC 3.3V (FT232)
(ESP) GPIO0 ----- VCC 3.3V (FT232)
```

But everytime sketch does not start after upload. This is not a code problem, because I try start "blink" sketch or other. Everytime ESP work once, after upload.

Comment: https://github.com/esp8266/esp8266-wiki/wiki/Boot-Process

Comment: sounds like you're leaving it in programming mode, which the first reboot after a flash ignores...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you gre_gor. You were right about correct pins. If you want start ESP on "normal mode" you must plug pins like:

```
(ESP) GND ------- GND
(ESP) GPIO15 ---- GND
(ESP) VCC ------- VCC 3.3V
(ESP) EN -------- VCC 3.3V
(ESP) GPIO0 ----- VCC 3.3V
(ESP) GPIO2 ----- VCC 3.3V
```

But if we must use GPIO0, GPIO2 and GPIO15 how we have 9 GPIO, 2 UART and 1 ADC?

Answer (score 0):

For me the same issue happened once ,i tries flashing the AT commands firmware (can download from espressif website)and then burned my test firmware to it ...worked.Try it..!